# Server side includes on app engine (<!-- include virtual="header.html" -->)?

Tags: google-app-engine, server-side-includes

I have been trying to figure this out a while. I would like to make my app engine website use basic html and shtml whenever in order to avoid the slow warm-up phase of jsp apps on app engine. This is so that my landing pages load instantly.

Basically, I am trying to include an html file into my main html file (index.html - I tried index.shtml). This is the command I try:

```
<!-- include virtual="header.html" -->
```

However it does not work. The server side includes to not seem to get executed in app engine. Do I need to enable these commands somewhere first - or does app engine simply not allow them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSI is a web-server-specific feature that [GAE appears not to support](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg17509.html).

(This per [Nick Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson), who's quite active on this site.)

Comment: Correct. SSI, to the best of my knowledge, isn't part of the Java Servlet spec, either.

Comment: What is the supported alternative on App Engine?

Comment: Was their ever a response to this. I would like to do something similar.